# My function keeps returning None even though it has a return statement

Tags: python, function

I have a very short function located within a class that keeps returning `None`, even though I have turned what was previously a print statement into a return statement, here's what I have:

```
def explain(self):
    return(print('Wear a', self.getColor(), 'shirt')
```

The statement will print out but every time it prints `None` on the next line, please let me know how I can stop this from happening!

Comment: Hey! If your query was resolved, don't forget to [accept one of the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) below :)

Answer (score 5):

This is because the output of the `print` is printed on the terminal, and the value of the `print` function in itself is a `None`, which is what is returned.

If you wish to return the value as well as print it, you can do something like:

```
def explain(self):
    string = 'Wear a' + self.getColor() + 'shirt'
    print(string)
    return string
```

If only returning the value is needed, simply remove the print statement in the above and you can print it later.

Answer (score 0):

`return` statement is not a function. It is a control flow construct (like `if-else`). It is what lets you "take data with you between function calls". So, you can't return `print`, because it's not a function, it's a reserved word. But since `print` is a statement, you see it's output on the terminal, but `None` as well, since nothing is returned by the function. If you wish to return a string, do like this :

```
return 'Wear a ' + self.getColor() + ' shirt'
```